# what's the mean of const isType = <T>(type: string) => (obj: unknown): obj is T => toString.call(obj) === `[object ${type}]`

Tags: typescript, function

```
const isType = <T>(type: string) => (obj: unknown): obj is T =>  toString.call(obj) === `[object ${type}]`
```

I know it's a function about judging types, but it uses a lot of arrows and I don't understand what the arrows at each stage mean

```
const isType = <T>(type: string) => (obj: unknown): obj is T
```

The first part indicates that the function accepts a parameter and returns a boolean value of type judgment

```
=>  toString.call(obj) === `[object ${type}]`
```

what the latter part means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this simplified example:

```js
function isType<T,>(type: string) {
    return function (obj: unknown): obj is T {
        return toString.call(obj) === `[object ${type}]`
    }
}

const foo = isType('hello')([])
```

`isType` is a function `<T>(type: string) =>` which returns another function  `(obj: unknown): obj is T`. THis another function is a typescript [custom typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

However, `toString` is not a typeguard itself, hence, I' m not sure if this partial function/typeguard is useful

Comment: Can it be understood as  ` toString.call(obj) === `[object ${type}]``   is an implementation of (obj: unknown): obj is T ?

Comment: @cui , yes, it is an implementation (or body) of `function (obj: unknown): obj is T`

Answer (score 0):

Let's give it a try. Just to start with, I don't think this does what is supposed to do.

The function is returning another function, that will act as a type guard. That means that TS can use it to narrow types.

You can consider `isType` as being a [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).
You'll need to make 2 calls for this to actually work

1. one to get a type guard
2. to actually call the type guard